# Implementing inherited functions in derived trait's implementation block

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
trait A {
    fn foo(&self);
}

trait B {
    fn bar(&self);
}

trait C : A + B {
}

struct S;

impl A for S {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("In S->foo()");
    }
}

impl B for S {
    fn bar(&self) {
        println!("In S->bar()");
    }
}

impl C for S {
}

fn main() {
    let s = S;
    s.foo();
    s.bar();
}
```

(Rust playground link: http://is.gd/pde2LE)

Is it possible to only implement `C` for `S` and implement the `foo` and `bar` functions in that implementation block? I tried the following but it fails:

```
trait A {
    fn foo(&self);
}

trait B {
    fn bar(&self);
}

trait C : A + B {
}

struct S;

impl C for S {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("In S->foo()");
    }

    fn bar(&self) {
        println!("In S->bar()");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S;
    s.foo();
    s.bar();
}
```

(Rust playground link: http://is.gd/CqA6J5)

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on Veedrac's comment: no, it is not possible, in particular because trait inheritance does not mean the same thing as inheritance on OO languages like Java.

In Rust trait inheritance is much closer to Haskell's type class inheritance. If trait `A` inherits trait `B`:

```
trait A: B { ... }
```

It only means that "if some type `T` implements `A`, it must also implement `B`". It is not "is-a" relationship, it is a special constraint. The traits themselves are still disjoint. Therefore, you must explicitly implement trait `B` if you want to implement `A` for your type.